# Unable to update sitemap.xml file on Run time

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

On local machine it is working file but on AWS it's not work
**path on local machine = 'sitemap.xml'**
**on aws server  = '/var/www/html/sitemap.xml'**

```
$ch = curl_init();
// Set cURL options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
// Execute cURL request
$response = curl_exec($ch);    
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
        echo 'Error: ' . curl_error($ch);
    }
    // Close cURL session
    curl_close($ch);
    // Handle response
    if ($response) {
      $xml = simplexml_load_file('/var/www/html/sitemap.xml');
      unset($xml->url);
        $urlElement = $xml->addChild('url');
        $urlElement->addChild('priority','1.0');
        $urlElement->addChild('loc', 'base url');
        $urlElement->addChild('lastmod', date('Y-m-d'));
        $blogUrls = json_decode($response,true);
      for ($i = 0; $i < count($blogUrls['DATA'][0]); $i++) {
       // print_r($blogUrls['DATA'][0][0]['URL']) . '<br>';
        if ($blogUrls['DATA'][0] && $blogUrls['DATA'][0][$i] && $blogUrls['DATA'][0][$i]['URL']) {
          $urlElement = $xml->addChild('url');
          $urlElement->addChild('priority','0.9');
          $urlElement->addChild('loc', 'baseUrl'.$blogUrls['DATA'][0][$i]['URL']);
          $urlElement->addChild('lastmod', $blogUrls['DATA'][0][$i]['DATE']);
        }
      }
      $xml->asXML('/var/www/html/sitemap.xml');
    } else {
        // API call failed, handle the error
        // echo 'API call failed';
    }
```

Comment: it doesen't give you any error?

Comment: no @Alessandro it is working file on my local machine

Comment: And on aws it doesen't return an error or an error code?

Comment: unfortunately  no

Comment: is the code inside the `if ($response) {` executed? Try to echo $response and see what happen in the curl.

Comment: it  print complete response data

Comment: every things working file 
i have doubt may be AWS not give the permission to write it or may we path related issue

Comment: What is returnerd by this function `$xml->asXML('/var/www/html/sitemap.xml');`?

Comment: SimpleXMLElement Object()

Comment: Weird, from the official php page: "If the filename isn't specified, this function returns a string on success and false on error. If the parameter is specified, it returns true if the file was written successfully and false otherwise."

Comment: it could be version issue but i am not sure

Comment: try to save the file in the directory you are actually in `$xml->asXML('sitemap.xml');` and see if it works

Comment: no it is not work

Comment: Then is possibly a problem of permission on the file system

Comment: yes you are right  @Alessandro
now it is working fine after give the permission

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in comments it was a file system permission issue.